# Spliting multiple valued column of a table in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a Hive table as:

```
"Rinalytics Advisors"       "5-10 yrs"       "Bengaluru/Bangalore Mumbai"
```

Above represents the three columns of the table that i have. I need to split the third column as specified here into two different rows the values are separated with space in the table.

The expected output will be as:

```
Rinalytics Advisors     5-10 yrs         Bengaluru/Bangalore
Rinalytics Advisors     5-10 yrs         Mumbai
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c1,
       c2,
       city
FROM table LATERAL VIEW explode(split(c3," ")) adTable AS city;
```

[Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) you have doc about `LATERAL VIEW`.